# How to copy table data from one db to another?

Tags: postgresql

How can I do this when the table has a constraint and already exists in both databases? I need to rewrite the data in the table on my server with the data in the table on my development computer.

I have tried various forms of pg_dump, using both plain-text and binary formats. I have also tried using the --clean and --data-only options, but what always gets me when I try to restore is the constraint on the table.

```
pg_restore -O -d database_name dump.pg
```

Results in this error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2409; 0 56001 TABLE DATA attendees
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "attendees": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "attendees_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(237) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY attendees, line 1
WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 1
```

I'm trying to do this using just pg_dump/pg_restore with no editing of the server db between running the two commands. In other words, I don't want to have to go in and manually `drop table attendees cascade` before running the restore.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

No, you probably can't do that automatically.  If you are trying to dump and restore only fragments of the dependency chains, `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` have no way of knowing what your intentions are.  You are most likely going to need to spell them out for it, by supplying your own supplementary pre/post commands.

It is possible you could make a custom file to supply to `pg_restore`'s `-L` command which correctly drops and recreates the constraints you need.